# Unit test error in Xcode 9 and Simulator iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ios-simulator

I get the following error in Xcode 9 and Simulators with iOS 11. It's very weird as all the test cases are running fine in Xcode 9 with simulator iOS 9. It seems to be some kind of issue with Xcode 9 and Simulator iOS 11.

> Assertion failure in void _XCTestMain(XCTestConfiguration *)(),
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-13201/Sources/XCTestFramework/Harness/XCTestMain.m:62
>   2017-11-06 16:26:51.080851-0600 xctest
>
> [17644:81518] Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No test bundle found at
>   file:///Users/xxxx/Code/iOS-SDK/ContentSDK/build/Debug/ContentSDKTests.xctest/

Comment: Try deleting your test bundle and starting over with a new test bundle.

Comment: @matt I tried deleting the test bundle and added new but it doesn't work

Comment: That's weird. I suggest that you try this with a completely new empty project, to convince yourself that texts do work just fine in Xcode 9 with an iOS 11 simulator.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. It started happening when I added a subproject. Interestingly as in your case the tests fail in iOS 11, but work fine in iOS 10.3.3. They fail on CI as well, not only on my machine.

Comment: @mokagio - My project also had a subproject. I presume something messed up in project file or simulator. Now I tried with Xcode 9.3.1 and my test works in all the OS versions. I would recommend try first in Xcode 9.3 else try add a simulator and run the test in the new simulator.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was in the lowercase letter in 'build' directory name. I used parameter '-derivedDataPath build' for xcodebuild. Try to compare the real build directory name on the filesystem with the name in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wired issue. I have created a simulator from Xcode -> window-< Devices & simulators and the unit test started working fine.